# Unexpected Bash Output

Tags: bash, puppet

Can someone explain why I got error messages related to puppet when I type `foo` at the bash prompt as shown below:

```
[root@centos8 ~]# foo
bash: foo: command not found...
Failed to search for file: Failed to download gpg key for repo 'puppet5': Curl error (37): Couldn't read a file:// file for file:///etc/pki/rpm-gpg/RPM-GPG-KEY-puppet5-release;file:///etc/pki/rpm-gpg/RPM-GPG-KEY-2025-04-06-puppet5-release [Couldn't open file /etc/pki/rpm-gpg/RPM-GPG-KEY-puppet5-release;file:///etc/pki/rpm-gpg/RPM-GPG-KEY-2025-04-06-puppet5-release]
[root@centos8 ~]#
```

Why do I get the second line in the error message? I tried it with `"bar"` as a command; I got the same irrelevant error message.

Comment: https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/585835/failed-to-search-for-file-failed-to-download-gpg-key-for-repo-mariadb-main-c#comment1113916_585835

Comment: @PhilipCouling I linked to telcoM's comment specifically. Did you read that?

Comment: @muru apologies my browser jumped straight to the answer, not the comment, not sure why.  Yes I see your point.  That's the danger of link-only answers (and comments).

Comment: This ought to be marked duplicate but for the lack of an up-voted answer.  I've copied telcoM's comment into [an answer](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/602962/20140) since it basically is one. (community wiki to void rep sniping).